# How to remove the exact occurence of characters from a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

For Example, I have a string like :

```
string str = "santhosh,phani,ravi,phani123,praveen,sathish,prakash";
```

I want to delete the charaters `,phani` from `str`.

Now, I am using `str = str.Replace(",phani", string.Empty);`

then my output is : `str="santhosh,ravi123,praveen,sathish,prakash";`

But I want a output like : `str="santhosh,ravi,phani123,praveen,sathish,prakash";`

Comment: All 3 answers below, at this point in time are wrong, as they will not work if `phani` is the last element in the string. You are better off using Regex to match and replace.

Comment: Try to use Regex.Replace()

Comment: @bPratik Altough it is nice to be able to use Regex, I don't think it is really neccessary here. If this were to be a large string than it would be better to use a compiled Regex for performance, but I think a split and join is more readable here.

Comment: @Silvermind - yes, which is why you have my vote, but from a learners point of view, Regex is the solution to this category of issues and learning it is part of the trade :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
string str = "santhosh,phani,ravi,phani123,praveen,sathish,prakash";
var words = str.Split(',');
str = String.Join(",", words.Where(word => word != "phani"));
```

Comment: and we need to just add the namespace using system.linq;

Answer (score 2):

the better choice is to use a Split and Join method.
Easy in Linq :

```
String str = "santhosh,phani,ravi,phani123,praveen,sathish,prakash";
String token = "phani";
String result = String.Join(",", str.Split(',').Where(s => s != token));
```

*(edit : I take time for testing and i'm not first ^^)*

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
str = str.Replace(",phani,", ",");
```

This, however, does not work if "phani" is the last item in the string. To get around this, you could do this:

```
string source = "...";
source += ",";    // Explicitly add a comma to the end

source = source.Replace(",phani,", ",").TrimEnd(',');
```

This adds a comma, replaces "phani" and removes the trailing comma.

A third solution would be this:

```
str = String.Join(",", str.Split(',').ToList().Remove("phani").ToArray());
```

Comment: I know - I just changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use with comma instead of;

```
string str = "santhosh,ravi,phani,phani123,praveen,sathish,prakash";
str = str.Replace(",phani,", ",");
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Output will be;

```
santhosh,ravi,phani123,praveen,sathish,prakash
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/HeupAt)**.

As Davin [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245026/how-to-remove-the-exact-occurence-of-characters-from-a-string/15245083#comment21496793_15245083) in comment, this won't work if `phani` is last item in the string. Silvermind's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15245157/447156) looks like the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.join(",", str.split(',').ToList().remove("phani"));
```

Removes any given name from the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "santhosh,phani,ravi,phani123,praveen,sathish,prakash";
string pattern = @"\b,phani,\b";
string replace = ",";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(str, pattern, replace));
```

Output:

```
santhosh,ravi,phani123,praveen,sathish,prakash
```

Comment: What if "phani" is at the beginning or end of the string (i.e. not preceded or followed by the comma)?

Comment: Also `\b` doesn't make a sense much there, because comma itself is a word boundary character.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [the regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), but you have to take care of cases when your string starts or ends with the substring:

```
var pattern = @",?\bphani\b,?";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
var result = regex.Replace(input, ",").Trim(',');
```

Shorter notation could look like this:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @",?\bphani\b,?", ",").Trim(',');
```

**Explanation of the regular expression:** `,?\bphani\b,?` matches the word `phani`, but only if preceded and followed by word-delimiter characters (because of the word boundary metacharacter `\b`), and it can be (but doesn't have to be) preceded and followed by the comma thanks to `,?` which means none or more comma(s).

At the end we need to remove possible commas from the beginning and end of the string, that's why there's `Trim(',')` on the result.